# Change ports mirror in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, bsd, bsd-ports

The initial portsnap fetch command is talking forever. I'm getting speeds of 3427 Bps. Bps. So 3.4 KBps. Where's the config to change the mirror.

Please note I'm not talking about the actual building in ports, that's fine. I'm talking about downloading the ports tree.

Comment: There is a manual page for portsnap and portsnap.conf - you should look there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to a temporary server issues that should be fixed now, please try again.

Comment: This is the answer. Had the same problems. A developer on the FreeBSD forums stated they were having initial issues that were solved. Everything works fine as of 10 hours or so  from my commenting here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider git method of fetching ports as documented over here:

[FreeBSD Handbook - Ports Collection - Procedure: Git Method](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/ports/#ports-using)

Shallow `git-clone` with only latest commits will speed up process rapidly:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://git.FreeBSD.org/ports.git /usr/ports
```

Later (or when needed) You can make local repository to complete one by unshallowing:

```
cd /usr/ports
git fetch --unshallow
```

Comment: There are a number of ways to get a ports tree locally (portsnap, git, simple tar, etc.) The question was about portsnap specifically, so I was answering that. Personally, I'd recommend git without the `--depth 1`, but I was just answering the question as it was asked.

Comment: Sure I agree. I was in the exactly same situation and this approach helped to me.